# sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found. in kivy 2.0.0

Tags: python, kivy

When I am running this code in pycharm:

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

    class MainWidget(Widget):
       pass

    class GalaxyApp(App):
       pass

    GalaxyApp().run()
```

Then I got this error:
(  [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing *window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
File "C:\Users\LAHAVA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core_*init**.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
mod = **import**(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
File "C:\Users\LAHAVA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in 
from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.)

I have try reinstalling kivy and stuff but it not still work! Can anyone help me? This is an annoying problem.

Comment: Whats your Python version? If it is 3.9 then try to use 3.6.2 version and give feedback please. Also be sure installed some dependencies: `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`

Comment: It still not work

Comment: And also kivy 2.0.0 doesn't support for Kivy?